# Change the column value depends on occurrence count

Tags: mysql, sql

There is the table:

```
NAME   GENRE
book1  genre1
book2  genre2
book3  genre1
book3  genre2
book4  genre1
etc
```

So, we can have a book with only one or with many genres.
From this table I would like to obtain this table

```
NAME   GENRE
book1  genre1
book2  genre2
book3  mixed_genres
book4  genre1
```

So in the new table **if the book has only one genre, we keep this genre, if the book has many genres we change genre value by “mixed_genres”**.

There is any way to do this?
Many thanks for any advice!

Comment: Try to understand, how "count(*)" with "group by" works.
It will be an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select book,
       (case when min(genre) = max(genre) then max(genre)
             else 'mixed genres'
        end) as genre
from t
group by book;
```

You can also list out all the genres:

```
select book, group_concat(genre) as genre
from t
group by book;
```